# O elemento criado não pega as funcionalidades do javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, front-end

*Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
at HTMLDivElement.dragOver*

pessoal não sei por que, estava fazendo um projeto do MasterClass da *Rocketseat* onde é criado um quadro Kanban, eu estou adicionando a funcionalidade que quando o usuário clicar em um botão ele adiciona um novo cartão no quadro **To Do**. segue o código:

```js
//seleciona todos os elementos 'card' do HTML
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
//seleciona todas as 'dropzones'do HTML
const dropzones = document.querySelectorAll('.dropzone');
//seleciona os botões para adicionar ma nova tarefa
const addCard = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-add-card'); 

const dropzoneCreate = document.getElementById('status-to-do')


//função que adiciona uma nova tarefa
function criaDiv () {
    let newcard = document.createElement('div');
    return newcard;
}

function creatCard() {
    let newcard = criaDiv();
    newcard.innerHTML = `<div class="card" draggable="true">
                            <div class="status" ></div>
                            <div class="content"><input type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui"></div>
                        </div>`;

    dropzoneCreate.appendChild(newcard);
}

//para cada 'card' ele vai pegar os eventos
cards.forEach(card => {
    card.addEventListener('dragstart', startDragging);
    card.addEventListener('drag', dragging);
    card.addEventListener('dragend', endDragging);
});

function startDragging() {
    dropzones.forEach(dropzone => {
        dropzone.classList.add('highlight');
    });

    this.classList.add('ghost-card');
}

function dragging() {}

function endDragging() {
    dropzones.forEach(dropzone => {
        dropzone.classList.remove('highlight');
    });

    this.classList.remove('ghost-card');
}

//local onde serão soltados os cards
dropzones.forEach(dropzone => {
    dropzone.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
    dropzone.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
    dropzone.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
    dropzone.addEventListener('drop', drop);
});

function dragEnter() {}

function dragOver() {
    this.classList.add('over');
    const cardDragged = document.querySelector('.ghost-card')
    this.appendChild(cardDragged);
}

function dragLeave() {
    this.classList.remove('over');
}

function drop() {
    this.classList.remove('over');

}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: #130f0d;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.workspace {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 32px;
}

    .board {
        background-color: #141316;
        border: 1px solid #FD951f11;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 0 16px;
    }

        h3 {
            padding: 16px;
            color: #FD951Fcc;
        }

        .board button{
            float: right;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: -43px;
            font-size: 25px;
            padding-right: 37px;
            outline: 0 none;
            border: 0 none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

         button img{
            float: right;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 25px;
            outline: 0 none;
            border: 0 none;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .dropzone {
            padding: 16px;
            min-width: 282px;
            min-height: 200px;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }

        .highlight{
            background-color: #FD952f08;
        }

            .card{
                padding: 16px;
                box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px #FD951Fcc;;
                border-radius: 4px;
                width: 250px;
                margin: 25px 0px;
                font-size: 18px;
                background-color: #1a1a1c;
                transition: 0.5s;
            }


            .over {
                background-color: #4cd13711;
            }

            .ghost-card {
                cursor: move;
                opacity: 0.4;
                transform:  rotate(5deg);

            }

                #status-to-do > .card > :nth-child(0n+1){
                    background-color: aqua;
                }
                #status-doing  > .card > :nth-child(0n+1){
                    background-color: blue;
                }
                #status-done  > .card > :nth-child(0n+1){
                    background-color: red;
                }

                .status {
                    width: 30px;
                    height: 8px;
                    background-color: gray;
                    margin-bottom: 16px;
                    border-radius: 8px;
                }

                .content input {
                    outline: 0 none;
                    border: none;
                    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
                    background-color: #1a1a1c;
                    color: aliceblue;
                    font-size: 18px;
                }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;1,200;1,300;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/css/style.css">
    <title>Kanban Board</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="workspace">
        <li class="board">
            <h3>To Do</h3>
            <button class="btn-add-card" onclick="creatCard();">
                <img src="../../public/images/plus.svg" alt="A">
            </button>
            <div class="dropzone" id="status-to-do">
                <div class="card" draggable="true">
                    <div class="status" ></div>
                    <div class="content"><input type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="board">
            <h3>Doing</h3>
            <button>
                <img src="../../public/images/plus.svg" alt="A">
            </button>
            <div class="dropzone" id="status-doing">
                <div class="card" draggable="true">
                    <div class="status" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="content"><input type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="board">
            <h3>Done</h3>
            <button>
                <img src="../../public/images/plus.svg" alt="A">
            </button>
            <div class="dropzone" id="status-done">
                <div class="card" draggable="true">
                    <div class="status" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="content"><input type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script src="../../public/js/main.js"  defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Quando se clica no botão(no caso na imagem não carregada) ele adiciona o novo elemento direitinho, mas não pega as funcionalidades do javascript, sera que podem me ajudar? obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os event listeners `dragstart`, `drag` e `dragend` são registados apenas para os elementos card existentes no DOM. Quando novos elementos card são adicionados ao DOM, eles não têm quaisquer event listener registados e por isso não se comportam como os outros.

Para resolver isto, tal como o Augusto sugeriu, terá que registar esses event listeners sempre que adicionar um novo elemento card ao DOM. Alternativamente, pode utilizar "event delegation" pattern, ou seja, registar os event listeners em elementos que estejam sempre na DOM e depois o detectar o elemento através do `event.target`.

Abaixo fica o seu código com as devidas alterações para registar os eventos com "event delegation".

```js
//seleciona todos os elementos 'card' do HTML
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
//seleciona todas as 'dropzones'do HTML
const dropzones = document.querySelectorAll('.dropzone');
//seleciona os botões para adicionar ma nova tarefa
const addCard = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-add-card');

const dropzoneCreate = document.getElementById('status-to-do')


//função que adiciona uma nova tarefa
function criaDiv() {
  let newcard = document.createElement('div');
  return newcard;
}

function creatCard() {
  let newcard = criaDiv();
  newcard.innerHTML = `<div class="card" draggable="true">
                            <div class="status" ></div>
                            <div class="content"><input type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui"></div>
                        </div>`;

  dropzoneCreate.appendChild(newcard);
}

// Início: Registo de event listeners utilizando event delegation pattern
document.querySelector('.workspace').addEventListener(
  'dragstart',
  (event) => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('card')) startDragging(event.target);
  },
);

document.querySelector('.workspace').addEventListener(
  'drag',
  (event) => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('card')) dragging(event.target);
  },
);

document.querySelector('.workspace').addEventListener(
  'dragend',
  (event) => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('card')) endDragging(event.target);
  },
);
// Fim: Registo de event listeners utilizando event delegation pattern


function startDragging(card) {
  dropzones.forEach(dropzone => {
    dropzone.classList.add('highlight');
  });

  card.classList.add('ghost-card');
}

function dragging(card) {}

function endDragging(card) {
  dropzones.forEach(dropzone => {
    dropzone.classList.remove('highlight');
  });

  card.classList.remove('ghost-card');
}

//local onde serão soltados os cards
dropzones.forEach(dropzone => {
  dropzone.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
  dropzone.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  dropzone.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
  dropzone.addEventListener('drop', drop);
});

function dragEnter() {}

function dragOver() {
  this.classList.add('over');
  const cardDragged = document.querySelector('.ghost-card')
  this.appendChild(cardDragged);
}

function dragLeave() {
  this.classList.remove('over');
}

function drop() {
  this.classList.remove('over');

}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #130f0d;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.workspace {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

.board {
  background-color: #141316;
  border: 1px solid #FD951f11;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 16px;
}

h3 {
  padding: 16px;
  color: #FD951Fcc;
}

.board button {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -43px;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-right: 37px;
  outline: 0 none;
  border: 0 none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button img {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  outline: 0 none;
  border: 0 none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropzone {
  padding: 16px;
  min-width: 282px;
  min-height: 200px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #FD952f08;
}

.card {
  padding: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px #FD951Fcc;
  ;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 25px 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #1a1a1c;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.over {
  background-color: #4cd13711;
}

.ghost-card {
  cursor: move;
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}

#status-to-do>.card> :nth-child(0n+1) {
  background-color: aqua;
}

#status-doing>.card> :nth-child(0n+1) {
  background-color: blue;
}

#status-done>.card> :nth-child(0n+1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.status {
  width: 30px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.content input {
  outline: 0 none;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-color: #1a1a1c;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;1,200;1,300;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/css/style.css">
  <title>Kanban Board</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="workspace">
    <li class="board">
      <h3>To Do</h3>
      <button class="btn-add-card" onclick="creatCard();">
                <img src="../../public/images/plus.svg" alt="A">
            </button>
      <div class="dropzone" id="status-to-do">
        <div class="card" draggable="true">
          <div class="status"></div>
          <div class="content"><input type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="board">
      <h3>Doing</h3>
      <button>
                <img src="../../public/images/plus.svg" alt="A">
            </button>
      <div class="dropzone" id="status-doing">
        <div class="card" draggable="true">
          <div class="status">
          </div>
          <div class="content"><input type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="board">
      <h3>Done</h3>
      <button>
                <img src="../../public/images/plus.svg" alt="A">
            </button>
      <div class="dropzone" id="status-done">
        <div class="card" draggable="true">
          <div class="status">
          </div>
          <div class="content"><input type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script src="../../public/js/main.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gostei dessa implementação. +1

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou do jeito que eu queria

Comment: desculpa mas sou bem noob utilizando a plataforma, onde fica a opção de marcar como resolvida? obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Faltou apenas registrar os eventos `dragstart`, `drag` e `dragend` junto ao novo cartão criado na função `creatCard()`, o código existente apenas registra esses eventos aos cartões criados no *HTML*.

```js
//seleciona todos os elementos 'card' do HTML
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
//seleciona todas as 'dropzones'do HTML
const dropzones = document.querySelectorAll('.dropzone');
//seleciona os botões para adicionar ma nova tarefa
const addCard = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-add-card');

const dropzoneCreate = document.getElementById('status-to-do')


//função que adiciona uma nova tarefa
function criaDiv() {
  let newcard = document.createElement('div');
  return newcard;
}

function creatCard() {
  let newcard = criaDiv();
  newcard.innerHTML = `<div class="card" draggable="true">
                            <div class="status" ></div>
                            <div class="content"><input type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui"></div>
                        </div>`;
  /******************************************************
   ******************************************************
   ****Aqui adicione os eventos ao novo cartão criado**** 
   ******************************************************
   ******************************************************/
  newcard.addEventListener('dragstart', startDragging);
  newcard.addEventListener('drag', dragging);
  newcard.addEventListener('dragend', endDragging);

  dropzoneCreate.appendChild(newcard);
}

//**************************************************************
//Esse código será executado apenas um vez ao carregar o arquivo
//**************************************************************
cards.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener('dragstart', startDragging);
  card.addEventListener('drag', dragging);
  card.addEventListener('dragend', endDragging);
});

function startDragging() {
  dropzones.forEach(dropzone => {
    dropzone.classList.add('highlight');
  });

  this.classList.add('ghost-card');
}

function dragging() {}

function endDragging() {
  dropzones.forEach(dropzone => {
    dropzone.classList.remove('highlight');
  });

  this.classList.remove('ghost-card');
}

//local onde serão soltados os cards
dropzones.forEach(dropzone => {
  dropzone.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
  dropzone.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  dropzone.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
  dropzone.addEventListener('drop', drop);
});

function dragEnter() {}

function dragOver() {
  this.classList.add('over');
  const cardDragged = document.querySelector('.ghost-card');
  this.appendChild(cardDragged);
}

function dragLeave() {
  this.classList.remove('over');
}

function drop() {
  this.classList.remove('over');

}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #130f0d;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.workspace {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

.board {
  background-color: #141316;
  border: 1px solid #FD951f11;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 16px;
}

h3 {
  padding: 16px;
  color: #FD951Fcc;
}

.board button {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -43px;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-right: 37px;
  outline: 0 none;
  border: 0 none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button img {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  outline: 0 none;
  border: 0 none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropzone {
  padding: 16px;
  min-width: 282px;
  min-height: 200px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #FD952f08;
}

.card {
  padding: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px #FD951Fcc;
  ;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 25px 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #1a1a1c;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.over {
  background-color: #4cd13711;
}

.ghost-card {
  cursor: move;
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}

#status-to-do>.card> :nth-child(0n+1) {
  background-color: aqua;
}

#status-doing>.card> :nth-child(0n+1) {
  background-color: blue;
}

#status-done>.card> :nth-child(0n+1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.status {
  width: 30px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.content input {
  outline: 0 none;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-color: #1a1a1c;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;1,200;1,300;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/css/style.css">
  <title>Kanban Board</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="workspace">
    <li class="board">
      <h3>To Do</h3>
      <button class="btn-add-card" onclick="creatCard();">
                <img src="../../public/images/plus.svg" alt="A">
            </button>
      <div class="dropzone" id="status-to-do">
        <div class="card" draggable="true">
          <div class="status"></div>
          <div class="content"><input type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="board">
      <h3>Doing</h3>
      <button>
                <img src="../../public/images/plus.svg" alt="A">
            </button>
      <div class="dropzone" id="status-doing">
        <div class="card" draggable="true">
          <div class="status">
          </div>
          <div class="content"><input type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="board">
      <h3>Done</h3>
      <button>
                <img src="../../public/images/plus.svg" alt="A">
            </button>
      <div class="dropzone" id="status-done">
        <div class="card" draggable="true">
          <div class="status">
          </div>
          <div class="content"><input type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script src="../../public/js/main.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```